# Unable to mock NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, unit-testing, mockito

I don't seem to be able to mock NSUserDefaults. I want it to send back the data that I tell it too but instead, it sends back the data stored in it from when running the app.

I am using:

- `Specta`
- `Expecta`
- `OCMockito`

I have the following test:

```
describe(@"AppDelegate", ^{
    __block AppDelegate *appDelegate;

    beforeEach(^{
        appDelegate = [AppDelegate new];
    });

    afterEach(^{
        appDelegate = nil;
    });

    describe(@"application did finish launching with options", ^{
        beforeEach(^{
            [appDelegate application:nil didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:nil];

            NSUserDefaults *mockUserDefaults = mock([NSUserDefaults class]);
            [given([mockUserDefaults objectForKey:@"currentUser"]) willReturn:nil];

        });

        it(@"should have a login view controller as root view controller", ^{
            expect(appDelegate.window.rootViewController).to.beKindOf([ToALoginViewController class]);
        });
    });
});
```

So the above test fails because it actually returns some data for `currentUser`. What am I doing wrong?

---

Following on from what Ken Kuan said, I made the following changes:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSUserDefaults *userDefaults;

- (void)setUserDefaults:(NSUserDefaults *)userDefaults;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)setUserDefaults:(NSUserDefaults *)userDefaults {
    _userDefaults = userDefaults;
}
```

**AppDelegateSpec.m**

```
beforeEach(^{
    [appDelegate application:nil didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:nil];

    NSUserDefaults *mockUserDefaults = mock([NSUserDefaults class]);
    [appDelegate setUserDefaults:mockUserDefaults];
    [given([mockUserDefaults objectForKey:@"currentUser"]) willReturn:nil];

});
```

However, I still get the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can mock `NSUserDefaults`. I have this code which is working fine.
When you are mocking `NSUserdefaults` make sure you are stopping mock at the end of test case, otherwise it would cause errors in other places where you are using `NSUserDefaults`.

```
id userDefaultsMock = OCMClassMock([NSUserDefaults class]);

OCMStub([userDefaultsMock standardUserDefaults]).andReturn(userDefaultsMock);

OCMStub([[userDefaultsMock standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:SHOWMYNAME]).andReturn(@"N");

[self.myObject  codewithuserdefaults];

 OCMVerify( [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[OCMArg any] forKey:FIRSTNAME]);

[userDefaultsMock stopMocking];
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` in appDelegate which is actual user defaults, not your mock.

A solution is to make user default to a property of app delegate and set it with your `mockUserDefaults` in tests.

Another one is to swizzle `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` to return your `mockUserDefaults` in your tests.

Comment: I tried setting a property on the appDelegate and doing it that way but still got the same result. I updated my post to show the changes I made. Did I miss something?

Comment: Where did you use the user defaults in app delegate?

Comment: In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` I set `self.userDefaults` to `standardUserDefaults` and then straight away I check for the `currentUser` key. The outcome of this value then determines what to set the `rootViewController` as.

Comment: The mock will work only you use it. In your case, set mock is useless because you determine root view controller **before** you set the mock user defaults. You can clear `currentUser` key in `standardUserDefaults` in your tests or use second solution.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense now I think about it. I suppose one other way is that I just set the `rootViewController` to a loadingViewController and then from there check the userDefaults. This is probably the way the app was going to develop anyway.

Comment: I actually managed to do it without adding a new VC as I mentioned above. You can check out (and maybe comment on) my answer I provided. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

So with much thanks to Ken Kuan, I managed to solve the problem I was having. Heres how I achieved it.

I added a `NSUserDefaults` property to the `AppDelegate` and a setter function.

I set `self.userDefaults` to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` in `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

I then set the `rootViewController` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSUserDefaults *userDefaults;

- (void)setUserDefaults:(NSUserDefaults *)userDefaults;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    NSData *encodedUserData = [self.userDefaults objectForKey:@"currentUser"];
    if (encodedUserData) {
        NSLog(@"Have current user");
        self.window.rootViewController = [ThermostatViewController new];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No current user");
        self.window.rootViewController = [ToALoginViewController new];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)setUserDefaults:(NSUserDefaults *)userDefaults {
    _userDefaults = userDefaults;
}
```

**AppDelegateSpec.m**

```
describe(@"application will finish launching with options", ^{
    beforeEach(^{
        [appDelegate application:nil willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:nil];
    });

    context(@"application did finish launching with options and with no current user", ^{
        beforeEach(^{
            NSUserDefaults *mockUserDefaults = mock([NSUserDefaults class]);
            [appDelegate setUserDefaults:mockUserDefaults];
            [given([mockUserDefaults objectForKey:@"currentUser"]) willReturn:nil];

            [appDelegate application:nil didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:nil];
        });

        it(@"should have a login view controller as root view controller", ^{
            expect(appDelegate.window.rootViewController).to.beKindOf([ToALoginViewController class]);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't accept this for 2 days as its my own answer. In the meantime, feel free to improve on it.

Comment: I think you should put initial user default in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` and set root view controller in did finish load. Setting root view controller in didBecomeActive is unnecessary hence it will get invoked every time from background or resign active (e.g. Open control panel)